# Why are "i = ++i;" and "i = ++i + 2;" undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, operator-precedence

I found this article: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

I have no idea why `i = ++i;` and `i = ++i + 2;` are undefined behavior.

First example:

```
int i = 5;

i = ++i;
```

The result will be still 6.

If `i = ++i;` is stated as undefined behavior, then `i = ++j;` should be stated as undefined behavior too (Because assignment can happen before increment?).

Second example:

```
int i = 5;

i = ++i + 2;
```

The result will be still 8.

If `i = ++i + 2;` is stated as undefined behavior, then `i = ++j + 2;` should be stated as undefined behavior too (because assignment can happen before increment and sum)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What makes `i = ++i;` [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is that you're attempting to both read and write `i` in the same expression without a sequence point.

The increment performed by the `++` operator is considered a side effect, as is the assignment performed by the `=` operator.  Having two side effects on the same object, or a side effect and a read on the same object, is what causes problems.  It doesn't matter that any possible evaluation order will generate the same result.

`i = ++j;` is fine because no object is written to more than once or read and written in the same expression without a sequence point.

Comment: can you explain what is a sequence point?

Comment: @Adam 
Sequence point guarantees that left operand will be evaluated before second operand - for example comma is sequence point. For example: a, b. Comma guarantees that operand (variable) a will be evaluated before operand b.